# My google maps path symbol is not centered

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-polyline

Hello guys so i'm working on a project that includes a path symbol of a plane moving on a polyline and happens that it´s not centered has shown in
[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv0BR.png)

so I have this:

So here I declare the path symbol that is the **plane symbol**

```
var planeSymbol = {
    path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
    scale: 1,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokecolor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 1

};
```

**Next I set the polyline**

```
var GRU = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 38.771183, lng: -9.131135}, {lat: -23.6276104, lng: -46.6568016}], //Lis - GRU
    strokeOpacity: 0.3,
    icons: [ {
        icon: planeSymbol,
        offset: '0'
    } ],
                map: map
 });
 animatePlane(GRU);
```

**And then i set the moving symbol speed etc**.

```
function animatePlane(line) {
    var count = 0;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        count = (count + 0.01) % 200;
        var icons = line.get('icons');
        icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
        line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
}
```

I have started learning **html** and **javascript** by myself and I research a lot so any help you can give to me I'll be very glad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol), the `anchor` property of the symbol sets position of the symbol relative to the polyline.

> **anchor** | Type:  Point
>
> The position of the symbol relative to the marker or polyline. The coordinates of the symbol's path are translated left and up by the anchor's x and y coordinates respectively. By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.

With your `planeSymbol`, an anchor of (9,9) is approximately in the center:

```
var planeSymbol = {
  path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
  scale: 1,
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokecolor: 'black',
  strokeWeight: 1,
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)
};
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nvuyk7f7/3/)

[image: symbol with anchor at center]

**code snippet:**

```js
var planeSymbol = {
  path: 'M 8.1326447,0.80527736 C 8.5471666,0.063577346 9.742752,0.030177346 10.052431,0.82497736 C 10.093464,3.0114774 10.134497,5.1980774 10.17553,7.3845774 C 12.760407,8.9653774 15.345284,10.546179 17.930161,12.127079 C 17.930161,12.881779 17.930161,13.636479 17.930161,14.391179 C 15.373077,13.579479 12.815993,12.767779 10.258908,11.956179 C 10.27281,13.280479 10.286713,14.604879 10.300615,15.929279 C 10.8565,16.555879 11.412385,17.182479 11.96827,17.809079 C 12.25527,18.269479 12.437605,19.641079 11.59784,19.085079 C 10.804104,18.802179 10.010367,18.519179 9.21663,18.236279 C 8.3133108,18.620779 7.4099916,19.005279 6.5066724,19.389779 C 6.3952441,18.705879 6.2272708,17.857479 6.8519879,17.359679 C 7.2927717,16.882879 7.7335555,16.406079 8.1743393,15.929279 C 8.1465467,14.604879 8.1187541,13.280479 8.0909615,11.956179 C 5.5894706,12.824879 3.0879797,13.693479 0.58648883,14.562179 C 0.54479393,13.821679 0.50309893,13.081079 0.46140403,12.340579 C 3.0184842,10.717079 5.5755645,9.0935778 8.1326447,7.4700774 C 8.1326447,5.2484774 8.1326447,3.0268774 8.1326447,0.80527736 z',
  scale: 1,
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokecolor: 'black',
  strokeWeight: 1,
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 9)

};

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var GRU = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
      lat: 38.771183,
      lng: -9.131135
    }, {
      lat: -23.6276104,
      lng: -46.6568016
    }], //Lis - GRU
    strokeOpacity: 0.3,
    icons: [{
      icon: planeSymbol,
      offset: '0'
    }],
    map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 38.771183,
      lng: 0
    },
    map: map,
    icon: planeSymbol
  });
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: 38.771183,
      lng: 0
    },
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
    }
  })
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < GRU.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(GRU.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  animatePlane(GRU);
}

function animatePlane(line) {
  var count = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    count = (count + 0.01) % 200;
    var icons = line.get('icons');
    icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
    line.set('icons', icons);
  }, 20);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```